# How can I output the following grep command to a file?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I'm using crudini to add and remove sections and parameters to an ini file. After crudini runs, there are extra empty lines left in the file that I want to clean up, so that each section is separated by only 1 empty line. The grep command in the following function works but when I try to redirect the output to a file, I get a blank file as the result.

The code

```
sctn="Section Two"
mypath="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
my_ini=$mypath/test.ini
ini_sec=$sctn

function inidel () {
  crudini --del --verbose $my_ini "$ini_sec"
  grep -A1 . $my_ini | grep -v "^--$"
}

function iniadd () {
  crudini --set --verbose $my_ini "$ini_sec"
  grep -A1 . $my_ini | grep -v "^--$"
}
```

The data test.ini

```
 1| [Section One]
 2| Parameter1=x1
 3| Parameter2=example1
 4| Parameter3=one
 5|
 6| [Section Two]
 7| Parameter1=x2
 8| Parameter2=example2
 9| Parameter3=two
10|
11| [Section Three]
12| Parameter1=x3 
13| Parameter2=example3
14| Parameter3=three
15|
```

I've tried using `> $my_ini` after the grep command. I don't know what it is actually doing for sure but my guess is that it is writing the result for every line finishing with the last empty line. If I use `>> $my_ini` It writes correctly but appends the text instead of overwriting it.

Comment: this isn't the whole picture. what's `$sbd_ini`? Where & how do you call inidel and iniadd?

Comment: @Jeff Schaller, $sbd_ini was a mistake I've corrected it in my post, thanks. I'm currently calling the two functions manually in the shell to test it before adding it to other code.

Answer (score 1):

The double arrow (>>) is for appending data to a file,

Use a single arrow (>) to overwrite the file.

Comment: as stated in my question I've tried that but get an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to write to the same file I was operating on. If I use a temporary file then output it to my_ini it works.

Using my question's original code this works.

```
function inidel () {
  crudini --del --verbose $my_ini "$ini_sec"
  grep -A1 . $my_ini | grep -v "^--$" > tmpfile
  cat tmpfile > $my_ini
}
```

Using cat this works as well.

```
function inidel () {
  crudini --del --verbose $my_ini "$ini_sec"
  cat $my_ini > tmpfile
  cat -s tmpfile > $my_ini
}
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do this but not knowing any better, this is what I came up with and what I'll use.

Comment: `sed -i '$!N;/^\n$/!P;D' $my_ini`...